# Error publishing ASP.NET project with cpanel

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, cpanel

I have created a simple asp.net project. I want to publish this project.But when I want to publish the project with visual studio, there is no index.html in the generated files. That's why I see a page like in the picture.

[My internet site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjfVs.png)

[My cPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsWe9.png)

There is probably a very simple solution but I couldn't find it anywhere. What should I do. I would be glad if you could help.

Comment: I shared the same picture 2 times. But I still think it will be understood.

Comment: Am not sure you can host asp net website on cpanel. If am not mistaken cpanel is for linux platform, and Asp net runs on Windows platform only.

Comment: @IkennaEmman .Net Core (and therfore by extension ASP.Net Core) can run on Windows, Linux and MacOS

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core runtime on the server?

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate that it DotNetCore. Beside am not sure you can just host the dotnet app on cpanel without installing .Net core Platform on the system

Comment: @mxmissile 

how can i do it

Comment: @AhmetAydın  Ask Godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure you can host asp net website on cpanel. If am not mistaken cpanel is for linux platform, and Asp Net runs on Windows platform only.

Comment: I bought a site from godaddy. So how do I transfer this asp.net project. Do you know?